# Templates list in "Page Attributes" metabox is inaccurate

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template, custom-post-type-archives, page-attributes

This may be a simple fix but I've spent a few hours trying to resolve it already.

Template names that no longer exist are listed on the Page Attributes templates lists in the Wordpress Admin under Pages.

Templates like Adventures Main or People Main (see screenshot below), no longer exist as physical files. Adventures Main was the template name for archive-adventures.php and 'adventures' is the name for a custom post type that also no longer exists.

The file no longer exist and I even dropped the entire database and recreated the site locally, but strange enough and the template name still shows up on the list.

I have gone through all my templates and none has that name.

Is there a way to refresh the template list or where could this data still exist that causes the list to be inaccurate?

Screenshot:

[image: Worpdress Admin Page Attributes Template list]

Answer (score 0):

Turns out custom post type archieve files for CPTs like adventure, were still in my system (thanks to Dropbox messing up the file sync).

So, this is why I was still seeing some of the template names listed in Page Attributes. Lesson learned for anyone going through the same issue: always make sure the files are completely gone from your local or server.